# Как вывести русские буквы в консольном приложении?

Tags: c++

Приложение сделано в Visual Studio. Как вывести русские буквы в консольном приложении?

```
string stringl = "Применение алгоритма";
cout << stringl;
```

Comment: Погуглите на тему chcp "1251"

Comment: [Русский текст в консольных приложениях на C++](http://hashcode.ru/questions/12334/)

Comment: Обратите внимание на комментарий от @Angry Bird выше. В том вопросе на хэшкод все уже обсуждалось. Куча ответов. 

Пробуйте, но учтите **простого** решения **дури** в русской Винде с двумя кодировками нет.

Comment: <small>
Самый лучший способ поставить linux и забыть обо всем этом как о страшном сне ;)
</small>

Comment: В Винде тоже люди.

Answer (score 2):

Строку `system("chcp 866");` можно писать, если русского языка нет в командной строке. В подобных целях надо писать:

```
include <locale.h>
........
setlocale(0,"RUS");
```

Comment: Спасибо. `include <locale.h>`, все получилось.
`CharToOem` в MSVS выдает ошибку.

Comment: @elena, не забудьте принять ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Это для Builder, но думаю должно работать.
Объявляете функцию:

```
void rcout(char *string)             

{
char new_string[255];
CharToOem(string,new_string);
cout << new_string;
}
```

вызываете так:

```
rcout("Тут ваш текст");
```

Answer (score 0):

если работать в DevC++, то прямо в Мэйне, в самом начале до объявления вставляете

```
> setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian" ); 
> setlocale( LC_ALL," ");
```

Answer (score -1):

Во первых при выводе, переведите строку в массив чаров:

```
cout << stringl.c_str();
```

Ну и если это не поможет, попробуйте воспользоваться:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL,"Russian");
```

И еще, как написал [@KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) гугл имеет для Вас много ответов

Comment: cout << stringl.c_str(); это не перевод строки в массив чаров, это вывод массива, который содержится в классе string. И не важно, выводить так, или писать, как у автора. Правильно писать сразу setlocale.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <clocale> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus"); //"Rissian"
    cout<<"Великий могучий русский язык";
}
```